# Named scope for has-many and belongs-to association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, named-scope, sql-update

- RaceWeek has many picks
- Pick belongs to RaceWeek
- RaceWeek has a start_date attribute and an end_date attribute.
- Pick has a resolved attribute.

I want to return all picks associated with the RaceWeek records that fall between the (specified) start_date and end_date, AND then update all the resolved attributes in the pick records to 0.

What's the best way to accomplish this using combination of named_scopes or whatever else?  More efficient the better.  I'm ok with purely SQL solution.

I'm on Rails 2.3.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update using simple SQL query:

```
UPDATE picks SET resolved = 0
WHERE race_week_id IN
  (SELECT id FROM race_weeks
  WHERE start_date > '2011-01-15' AND end_date < '2011-06-15');
```